# ASP.NET MVC 5 roda no IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Tenho um site que está desenvolvido em ASP.NET Framework 4.5 MVC 5 e não está abrindo no IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008, mas no IIS Express Local do Windows 7 abre normal.

Falta algo para instalar no IIS?

Comment: Ola. Quando diz que o site não abre, aparece alguma mensagem de erro? Tem a `application pool` configurada correctamente (.NET4.0 com *Managed pipeline mode* em *Integrated*)? Precisa de dar mais alguma informação para que o possamos ajudar.

Comment: @Omni, então este é o problema, não dá erro nenhum, está configurado corretamente sim, abre a página de login, coloco o login e a senha e quando clico em "Entrar" a página fica em branco, não chega nem a carregar.

Comment: tente fazer assim, permita que a alguma pagina qualquer não precise de permissão de usuários, e me fale se continuou com a pagina branca... o iss esta configurado para rodar como virtual directory ou application?

Comment: Ja tive um problema desse uma vez, e consegui resolver seguindos os passos desse link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET4BreakingChangesAndStuffToBeAwareOf.aspx

Comment: @RafaelCabral, quando você diz pra permitir que a pasta não precise de permissão de usuário, onde é pra eu fazer isso, no código ou no iis ? Não manjo muito de iis. rs

Answer (score 1):

Tente as seguintes soluções:

- Instale o [HotFix KB 980368](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980368) no servidor no qual o IIS está instalado
- Caso o HotFix não funcionar, utilize a configuração abaixo:

  ```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  ```

Comment: o que é esse HotFix ? Esse segundo caso eu já tentei e não funcionou ..

Comment: Ele é "uma atualização que habilita certos manipuladores do IIS 7.0 e IIS 7.5 a manipularem requisições cujas URLs não terminam com um ponto".
Da última vez que passei por esses problemas, o que tive que fazer foi reinstalar o IIS por meio da linha de comando, DUAS VEZES. A primeira vez não funcionou, mas a segunda funcionou (não sei dizer o motivo). Sugiro que tente isso também, como uma possível alternativa.

Comment: Pra executar o comando você abre o CMD e vai pra pasta de instalação do dot Net framework, e então de lá executa  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis /i

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja alguma configuração não-habilitada. Tente isto:

1. Entre em 'Turn Windows Features on or Off' (ativar ou desativar recursos do windows)
2. Abra a aba 'Internet Information Services'
3. Abra a aba 'World Wide Web Services'
4. Abra a aba 'Application Development Features'
5. Selecione tudo.